# Combine results from different queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I have a simplified table setup as following:

Table 1 (products)

```
product_id    product_parent_id
646           45
```

Table 2 (category)

```
product_id    category_name
45            category_1
```

Table 3 (product_names)

```
product_id     slug
45             product45-details
646            product646-details
```

For product_id 646 I would like to get the category of product_id 45 and the slug of product 646 and combine them into one output.

So basically the result should be:

```
   id  link
   646 category_1/product646-details-detail
```

So far I have the following:

```
select product_id, CONCAT('I.category_name,'/',E.slug,'-detail') as link from products C left join product_names E on C.product_parent_id=E.product_id left join category H on E.product_id=H.product_id where C.product_id > 1 group by C.product_id
```

What would be the approach to get the result for E.slug based on the product_id and not the parent_parent_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `join`:

```
select p.product_id, c.category_name, pn.slug
from products p
inner join category c on c.product_id = p.product_parent_id
inner join product_names pn on pn.product_id = p.product_id
where p.product_id = 646
```